# Special characters with the VoiceRSS text-to-speech API

Tags: php, api, special-characters

I'm trying to make the VoiceRSS API working with french special characters and I don't manage to do it.

Here is my PHP code :

```
<?php

    $text = htmlentities("fédéré"); // "fédéré" means "federated"
    $filename = "test.mp3";

    $querystring = (http_build_query(array(
    "src" => $text,
    "key" => "e913cc4ffc2148f18ddfdcda118b7391",
    "hl" => "fr-fr",
    "r" => "0",
    "c" => "mp3",
    "f" => "22khz_16bit_mono"
    )));

    $url = "http://api.voicerss.org?".$querystring;
    $soundfile = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($filename,$soundfile);

    echo 'API = <a href="http://api.voicerss.org?'.$querystring.'" target="_blank">http://api.voicerss.org?'.$querystring.'</a><br /><br />';
    echo 'MP3 file generated = <a href="./'.$filename.'" target="_blank">'.$filename.'</a>';

?>
```

As it is, the word "fédéré" becomes :

`f%26Atilde%3B%26copy%3Bd%26Atilde%3B%26copy%3Br%26Atilde%3B%26copy%3B`

How could I resolve this in the URL and also in the sound of the MP3 file generated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `htmlentities()` on `$text` -- since you're using this in `http_build_query`, it will automatically encode the string for you.